# Leaks on componentsSeparatedByString and stringWithFormat, is there a better way to do this?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory, memory-leaks

I'm getting a bunch of memory leaks for this bit of code in Instruments.

Here:

```
NSArray *tmpCoords = [loc.mapCoords componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
```

and Here:

```
    coords.tileRow = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",x];
    coords.tileCol = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",y];
```

Is there a better way to do this? I'm basically parsing a string and adding stuff to an array. How do I clean this up?

Update: CoordinateArray is retained in .h and released in dealloc. Should have mentioned that earlier.
Full Code:

```
-(void)loadCoordinates
{
    NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];  
    // get list of coordinates once
    coordinateArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    MyAppDelegate *app = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    MyData *myData = app.data;

    NSArray *myArray = [myData locations];

    for ( NSUInteger i = 0; i < [myArray count]; i++ )
    {
        LocationModel *loc = [myArray objectAtIndex:i];
        NSArray *tmpCoords = [loc.mapCoords componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
        if ([tmpCoords count] < 2 ) continue;
        CoordinateModel *coords = [[CoordinateModel alloc] init];

        coords.row = [tmpCoords objectAtIndex:0];
        coords.col = [tmpCoords objectAtIndex:1];

        NSString *xString = [tmpCoords objectAtIndex:0];
        int x = [xString floatValue] / DEFAULT_TILE_SIZE;
        NSString *yString = [tmpCoords objectAtIndex:1];
        int y = [yString floatValue] / DEFAULT_TILE_SIZE;

        coords.tileRow = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",x];
        coords.tileCol = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",y];

        [coordinateArray addObject:coords];
        [coords release];

    }
    [pool release];   
}
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, are LocationModel and CoordinateModel CoreData auto-generated classes?

Comment: No, LocationModel and CoordinateModel are classes I created, that inherit from NSObject. They are not CoreData objects.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the properties on your Coordinate object are declared as either `retain` or `copy`, and you're forgetting to `release` them in your Coordinate's `dealloc` method.

The leaks instrument shows where the leaked object was created, not where it was lost.

Comment: Dave, good comment. However, coordinateArray is retain in .h and released in dealloc. Instruments does trace back to the two objects (componentsSeparatedByString, stringWithFormat). I admit, I don't see anything glaringly obvious either. Jordan